# Bootstrap 4 File Input Label Oveflows Column

Tags: bootstrap-4

I am trying to create a form using Bootstrap 4. But the label for the file input overflows the column. I couldn't find a way to make it fit in the column. Is there a bootstrap way or custom css that can achieve this?

Edit: I'm sorry that my question was not well explained. What I meant by the label is that the label in file input. That isi "Choose file...". As can be seen the file input in the image overflows on the right side. It is not aligned with the rest of input fields.

[image]

```
<div class="form-group row">
     <label for="image-upload" class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Resim Yükle (5:3 Oranlı)</label>

     <div class="custom-file col-sm-9">
           <input type="file" class="custom-file-input" id="image-upload" required>
           <label class="custom-file-label" for="image-upload">Choose file...</label>
           <div class="invalid-feedback">Example invalid custom file feedback</div>
     </div>
              <!--<div id="uploaded-images"></div> id=cover-image-input-->
</div>
```

Comment: Do you have a form tag?

Comment: @kiranvj Yes I do.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to separate your col-sm-9 and custom-file divs.

```
<div class="col-sm-9">
    <div class="custom-file">
        <input type="file" class="custom-file-input form-control" id="image-upload" required>
        <label class="custom-file-label" for="image-upload">Choose file...</label>
        <div class="invalid-feedback">Example invalid custom file feedback</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/qdfy91r5/1/

In addition, if you use the m-0 solution, it destroys your margins around every row. That answer only shows it in a one-row scenario, but you have multiple rows, which will squish them all together, as seen in the following fiddle that compares my answer to his:

https://jsfiddle.net/qdfy91r5/2/

Answer (score 0):

Simply give `m-0` ( margin: 0; ) to the `row` always because it gives horizontal scroll bar in your code sometimes.

You have .row classes that are not a child of .container or .container-fluid. Bootstrap requires .row be a direct child of  .container or .container-fluid because .row has a negative left/right margin that works within left/right padding in .container and .container-fluid. So the negative margins on .row are creating the horizontal scrollbar and for that you need to give `m-0` to the element.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="form-group row m-0">
     <label for="image-upload" class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Resim Yükle (5:3 Oranlı)</label>

     <div class="custom-file col-sm-9">
           <input type="file" class="custom-file-input" id="image-upload" required>
           <label class="custom-file-label" for="image-upload">Choose file...</label>
           <div class="invalid-feedback">Example invalid custom file feedback</div>
     </div>
              <!--<div id="uploaded-images"></div> id=cover-image-input-->
</div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I gave it mr-0 and this solved the problem but I can't understand why it works can you explain?. Giving mr-0 results in label text "Resim Yükle (5:3 Oranlı)" to indent as well so it is not aligned with the other labels. I also edited the question you might want to check it out.

Comment: do not fix it this way it is improper, your real issue is that you can't combine the custom-file and col-sm-9 classes. See my answer coming soon

Comment: this is the best way of dealing with row

Comment: actually this just removes all the bootstrap default margin info, which is what gives you the nice bootstrap look and spacing.  Simply creating a custom-file div inside of the default boostrap col-sm-x div makes it behave inside that container, without destroying the margins.

Comment: you are right but if smaller solution give you same result than bigger code solution, i prefer small code solution

Comment: @HalilKaragöz i explain all things i know, now your time to select best answer

Comment: I'm sorry, but it doesn't give the same solution. It destroys the margins between rows as well, with no spacing and looks terrible. Your example only shows it with one row, not many as he has.  See this fiddle to see the difference between your solution and mine.  https://jsfiddle.net/qdfy91r5/2/

Comment: @NishargShah erikrunia's answers is the right answer, dropping all margins or some is might give similar results but the main issue here was the wrong use of grid system, and he pointed out the right use